# how to validate uniqueness in expressjs, prisma and zod?

Tags: node.js, express, prisma, zod

question is simple, how to validate uniqueness using `Express.js`, `zod` and `prisma`? Im using `zod` and its `validateRequest` method to validate input like this

```
export const UsersModel = z.object({
  id: z.string().uuid(),
  name: z.string().min(7).max(20),
  password: z.string().min(7).max(20),
});
```

but apart from `name` being more than seven characters i also want it to be unique across the `Users` table.
I know i can put unique index on the column on the db level but is there an establish elegant way to do it in the code as well without manually browsing the table and checking whether such a record already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Uniqueness is something to be verified by your database itself, so this would be related to `prisma` and not the other records.

This is not possible with `zod` since that framework does not communicate with your database.

For reference on how to make a column or a data field unique, you can reference prisma's documentation on the [unique annotation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#unique).